# What is the difference beetween max connections per route and max connections total in apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, apache, feign

I'm trying to understand what is the difference between them. I tried to read the documentation but it does not help alot.

```
HttpClientBuilder
                    .create()
                    .setMaxConnPerRoute(maxConnectionsPerRoute)
                    .setMaxConnTotal(maxConnectionTotal)
                    .build();
```

It's the same of setDefaultMaxPerRoute and setMaxTotal from PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:

```
final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingmgr = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
poolingmgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(max);
poolingmgr.setMaxTotal(2 * max);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`setMaxConnTotal` is the total maximum connections available in the connection pool. 
`setMaxConnPerRoute` is the total number of connections limit to a single port or url.

Hope it is clear now

Comment: can anyone suggest what should be production values for this considering 1000 TPS traffic?

Comment: @Saurabhgalande  it should be at least  1000 TPS / (1 / TIME) = TIME * 1000 TPS  number of pool size.  Here TIME means how many seconds each request takes time in Seconds.  I.e   if On average, server responds in 0.5 second and your TPS=1000,   then pool size of 500 should be lower limit.